# numpy count frequency in more than one array

Tags: python, numpy

I have 3300 128x128 array(images), I would like to count the unique colours in these image.

```
np.unique(task, return_counts = True)
```

could give me the unique colour and the counts for one single image.

But in order to get the representation of all these 3300 images. I would like to get a unique result of all these images at the counts as well.

It's easy to get the unique colour,  but the counts is difficult to get.

Someone could help?

Comment: What is  a color? Is arr[0][0] the color of pixel (0,0)?

Comment: Use `axis` param with `np.unique`.

Comment: @AndyHayden Hi, the color means the different values in [0,255] if the image is a RGD image, the image is 128x128 pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    colors = torch.tensor([])
for i in range(len(Image_list)):

    img_dir = My_directory.format(sub_idx)

    img_str = parc1a_list[i]

    img_arr = io.imread(os.path.join(parc1a_dir, parc1a_str))

    img_tensor = torch.from_numpy(img_arr)

    unique_color = torch.unique(img_tensor).type(torch.FloatTensor)
    colors = torch.cat((colors,unique_color))
colors = torch.unique(colors)
print(colors)
sorted_color, indices = torch.sort(colors)
```

Sorry My question wasn't clear. I want to count 3000 images unique color.
I create a for loop looping through all the 128x128 images and count the number.
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't totally clear, but I think you are asking about the best way to get a count of the occurrences of unique colors across all the images, essentially making a histogram of all the colors.  In this case the histogram would have 3000 x 128 x 128 data points, correct?

If so, the easiest implementation is to use a dictionary (or defaultdict) as the data structure, with the colors as the keys and the count of each color as the value.  Or you could use the `Counter` module.

You should be able to find examples such as:

[How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list of arrays to [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
In [11]: a = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3]])

In [12]: b = np.array([[5, 6], [1, 3]])

In [13] np.unique([a, b], return_counts=True)
Out[13]: (array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6]), array([2, 2, 2, 1, 1]))
```

*Note: The output of np.unique is sorted.*